# Installing Ghost.py on windows 8

Tags: python, pyqt, anaconda, ghost.py

For starters, I strongly dislike whoever made that website builder called "ghost" cause it makes this topic so annoying to search.

Anyways, I am trying [these instructions](http://ghostpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and it seems like I'm good.

Step 1) get PyQt, I have anaconda, so that is already there. Just to play it safe, I start by typing (in cmd):

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
#we're all up to date and ready to go...
```

and finally,

```
conda install PyQt
```

It returns saying:

```
#all requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Users\(my name)\Anaconda:
```

Step 2) Install Flask. (I have pearl as well...so it needs the .exe)

```
pip.exe install Flask
```

returns:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask in 
C:\Users\(my name)\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages
```

I guess that means it's there?

Step 3) install paste

```
pip.exe install paste
```

returns: the same thing as Flask

Step 4) Install Ghost.py, tried the previously mentioned instructions, said it didn't exist. After digging around, it looks like using the same method, "pip.exe install Ghost.py" is the way to go, I do that, and again, cmd tells me the same think as Flask and paste, same path and everything.

So, I copy and paste the exact example in the instructions first mentioned into pycharm, and I guess we're gonna look at ebay...well, I navigate to the directory that my python script is in, and when I attempt to run the file it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "ghostPY.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ghost import Ghost
ImportError: No module named ghost
```

So that's where I'm at. What am I missing? Where do I go from here? Just as a side measure, I also installed PySide using anaconda, it installed, and gave me the same result as above.

Thank you in advance for the help! Y'all are great!

Comment: Check that PyCharm is using the correct Python interpreter. Since it sounds like you've installed the required packages into Anaconda, you need to make sure you're using `C:\Users\(your name)\Anaconda\python.exe`

Comment: Ah, didn't think of that. Figured python was python haha I will try that when I get home :)

Answer (score 1):

Ghost.py is considered to be pre-release by pip so you need to use the `--pre` flag:

```
pip install pyside
pip install ghost.py --pre
```

Comment: Please add some explanatory text to your code. This ensures everyone will be able to understand it, and avoid unnecessary downvotes.